# How to Use Dropbox Access Token of Visualforce Page in Different Apex Class To Make an HTTP Callout

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, accesstoken

I have created a visualforce page to get the code initially and after the code with redirect url I'm getting the Access Token of Dropbox.

After that now I'm confused that How I can use this in the real-time apex call to make a callout using HTTP Calls how can we get the Access token from the visualforce page to make a callout in the different apex class.

Here is the Blog that I have used for the Access Token DROPBOX:

http://forceguru.blogspot.com/2014/05/dropbox-authentication-in-salesforce.html

But How we can consume this in different apex class because for this visualforce page which we are using for an access token is having redirect URL?

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an authentication process. Ordinarily, you'd store the access token somewhere (e.g. a Custom Setting or Custom Metadata), and then when you need to make the real-time API calls, you'd retrieve that data for use in your callout. You would not want to call this page for every API call.

Comment: Do you think the access token is not going to Expire? so that time I have to call again know?

I don't know how much time the access token is going to expire maybe in 24 hours?

Comment: @VINOD During the OAuth process, you'll get two tokens: the first is the access token you use for API access, and the second is a refresh token, that you use to get a new access token. See [the docs](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide). Note: you could also just use [Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_named_creds_and_ext_creds.htm&type=5), which takes care of this process for you.

Comment: *****The authentication provider didn't provide a refresh token. If the access token expires, your org won't be able to access this named credential ********

I have tried using Named Crends due to above message it is expring after 1 day Not sure how to fix the above one. 

Thank you so much @sfdcfox

Comment: @VINOD Did you read the doc link from above? You need to include `token_access_type=offline` to get a refresh token. Named Credentials should work just fine as long as you include the correct parameters.

Comment: Sorry I have read the document when Started this process, I tried initially Named Crends Itself a lot, but it didn't work.

Named Crendtials Scope I have included the param  `token_access_type=offline` & also with `Auth. Provider` scope as well it didn't work, that's why I went to Visualforce Page way of doing it!

Now also I have tried, when I'm trying to save Named Crends it is saying  `Error 400 Cannot find scope with name token_access_type=offline`

Comment: Sorry it is working fine now, I have made a mistake by reading once again that document I got to know the answer, thank you so much @sfdcfox